# django session check for existance

Tags: python, django, session

I am trying to check if the session does have anything in it. What I did is:

```
if request.session: 
   # do something
```

but it is not working. Is there any way of knowing whether the session contains something at that moment?

If I do `request.session['some_name']`, it works, but in some cases, I just need to know if the session is empty or not.

Asking with some specific names is not always a wanted thing.
Eg. if there is no session, it returns an error, since `some_name` doesn't exist.

Comment: `request.session` is dict, so you can try `if len(request.session.keys()) > 0` to check any items present.

Comment: @Rohan `request.session` is not a dict. It's an instance of `SessionBase` object which behaves like dict.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`request.session` is an instance of `SessionBase` object which behaves like dictionary but it it is not a dictionary. This object has a "private" field ( actually it's a property ) called `_session` which is a dictionary which holds all data.

The reason for that is that Django does not load session until you call `request.session[key]`. It is lazily instantiated.

So you can try doing that:

```
if request.session._session:
    # do something
```

or you can do it by looking at keys like this:

```
if request.session.keys():
    # do something
```

Note how `.keys()` works:

**django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py**

```
class SessionBase(object):
    # some code

    def keys(self):
        return self._session.keys()

    # some code
```

I always recommend reading the source code directly.

Comment: As mentioned by @freakish above, you can get a bunch of session in django just by doing `request.session._session`, it's returning a session key with value as a `dict`

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there's a convenience method on the session object

`request.session.is_empty()`